# JavaScript - Removing/adding button classes

Tags: javascript, class, button

I have a navigation Pane with multiple buttons (simplified to two for this example)

- Button 1 (Button Class = Secondary)
- Button 2 (Button Class = Secondary)

When clicking one of the buttons i need the button clicked to go to button class primary and the others to go to secondary. My way of currently doing this is quite long and convoluted and i was hoping someone might be able to make it more seamless.

**My method**

```
 function toggleButton1on(){
   $("#Button 1").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
   $("#Button 2").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
   $("#Button 1").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-primary");
   $("#Button 2").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-primary");
   $("#Button 1").addClass("btn btn-space btn-primary");
   $("#Button 2").addClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");

}



function toggleButton2on(){
   $("#Button 1").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
   $("#Button 2").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
   $("#Button 1").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-primary");
   $("#Button 2").removeClass("btn btn-space btn-primary");
   $("#Button 2").addClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
   $("#Button 1").addClass("btn btn-space btn-secondary");
}
```

Comment: `#Button 1` and so on should not work. IDs cannot have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the selector issue, it sounds like all you really need to do is toggle the `btn-secondary` and `btn-primary` classes, ignore the rest:

```
function toggleButton1On(){
    $("#button1").removeClass("btn-secondary").addClass('btn-primary');
    $("#button2").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass('btn-secondary');
}
```

But, if at all possible, it would make more sense to have a *default* style applied to buttons (say, instead of a `btn-secondary` class)`, and then simply toggle *on* the` btn-primary` class when needed:

```
function toggleButton1On(){
    $("#button1").addClass('btn-primary');
    $("#button2").removeClass("btn-primary");
}
```

Or, more generally:

```
const $btns = $('btn');
$btns.on('click', function() {
  $btns.removeClass('btn-primary');
  $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have space in id of the element.
And you don't have to remove and add classes that never change. I think it will make the code look much cleaner.